# Can't post a new question - there's a 7 day wait?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I was going to post a question tonight but got this notice instead:

> You have reached your question limit It looks like you might need a
>   break - take a breather and come back soon!
>
> You've asked 2 questions recently, some of which have not been
>   received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own
>   pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your
>   questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account
>   from asking questions entirely.
>
> It's been 1 days since you asked your last question. We ask that you
>   wait 7 days before asking again. Use this time to revisit your
>   previous questions, editing to address any issues that folks have
>   pointed out in comments.

It's true that I posted one question that was poorly received by the community - and also deleted now - but the second question I posted has a current net upvote of + 3.

Is the IPS site requiring that a user's *most recent* 2 questions have a net positive upvote or else there is a 7 day wait until they are allowed to post again?  If so, it seems overly restrictive.

Comment: Deleted questions/posts are weighted, they count pretty heavily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, you've run afoul of the low quality question ban algorithm. The details are kept secret by Stack Exchange, so I have no way of knowing what exactly set it off. Obviously, downvoted posts hurt you, even if they've been deleted, and [you do have one of those](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/9208/102) (score at -8; deleted by the community).

Unfortunately, I can't tell you any more than that about your specific case; I don't have any other information... but you do. That page you quoted has a lot more explanation on it... keep reading.

As far as I know, the algorithm's parameters do not vary among most Stack Exchange sites, and I doubt an exception would be made for Interpersonal Skills. At this point, the only thing you can do is wait. At any rate, though, seven days isn't too bad. I think very few users here ask questions more than once or twice a week anyway.

Comment: HDE, apaul's comment (see above) seems to suggest otherwise - that he knows the deleted questions / posts are *weighted* and count pretty "heavily".  So, I'm a little confused here.  Should I just ignore his comment?

Comment: @D.Hutchinson Both apaul *and* HDE are correct and describing things accurately. We know *some* things about the algorithms, but we don't know the exact numbers or equations, so we don't know exactly how heavy "heavily" is for example. We just know that both deletions & downvotes push a user toward these pacing mechanisms, and deletions seem count for much more than a downvote does. That information seems to be deliberately kept under wraps so that nobody can game the automated pacing systems, which is for the better.

Comment: @D.Hutchinson What doppelgreener said. We know some things, but not a whole lot. You've got pretty much all of the relevant information in that message.

Answer (score 4):

> You've asked 2 questions recently, some of which have not been received very well by the community. Everyone learns at their own pace, and it’s okay to make some mistakes. However, the reception your questions have received thus far might ultimately block your account from asking questions entirely.

Based on that network-wide automated message it looks clear that by stopping questions for a week, the system is both warning and ***protecting*** a user in that position from suffering a much longer blanket ban of 6 months or more on asking questions on this website. It also implies that this won't be a problem in future as long as the user does not ask further questions that get heavily downvoted or deleted by the community.

This matter is covered in detail in the following help pages:

https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/asking-rate-limited

https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans

The network-wide canonical reference about the longer-term question bans is here (thanks to user @[Jefromi](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2798/jefromi)):

[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)